# For a personal domain name better user lastname.com or firstname.lastname.com?

Tags: seo, domains, personal-website, branding

my name is Pierre Aribaut (Aribaut is the last name), i own aribaut.com but i didn't really use it yet, as i used to use my nickname as domain name.
I'm thinking of using this domain name instead of my nickname zetrader, not to be restricted to the financial theme (talking a lot about health on my website zetrader could be seen as strange?).
But before make the move, i'm asking myself what's better in terms of personal branding and seo :
1) aribaut.com
2) pierre.aribaut.com

What would you choose and why?
Thanks for the answers,

Pierre

Comment: What are you planning to rank for with a personal website?   If it is just your fairly unique name, it isn't like there is going to be lots of competition.

Comment: I plan to talk a lot about health, dietetic, sport, aging... better use my real name as domain name than a domain name using my nickname zetrader, no? Or it doesn't matter?

Comment: The TLD `.NAME` should be exactly tailored to your needs: while it is not the case anymore (still possible but not mandatory), this TLD was selling only third level domain names.

Answer (score 1):

The first option is preferred in my experience. Subdomain generally ranks lower than domain, and requires additional dns records (and you have to own the first option to get the second)

Comment: Thank you, i already have both (1 and 2) , just wondering which one to use (and make the other one redirect to the one i'll use).

Comment: I suggest using the first. As to putting a redirect in, use cname records